# Glassfish 4 JACC permission fails on EJB TimerService method

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, glassfish-4

I get the following log message when an EJB timer method executes:

```
JACC Policy Provider: Failed Permission Check, context(null)- permission(("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread"))
```

The method seems to work correctly, but I would like to eliminate the warning if possible.

Can someone explain what causes the message?  And perhaps how to fix it?

I'm using Glassfish 4.0.